# Do you need a browser to use webrtc?

Tags: android, mobile, webrtc, p2p

Do you need one? Or can you use it in a mobile app? And if you can, and you are working on android, how do you put the html code inside, without using webview? (since it doesnt support webrtc)

Comment: Hybrid apps on Android cannot utilize Webrtc yet(supposedly coming up soon). However, there are plenty of examples of native apps for both Android and iOS that work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a browser to use WebRTC. [Google has sample applications for Android and iOS](http://www.webrtc.org/native-code). These are built using native code, which means there is no HTML; you use Java or Objective-C to handle the same API.

Comment: If you find StackOverflow responses or comments helpful, mark them as such using the up/down arrows shown on the page. This helps other people to find useful answers.

Comment: This also helps people who write answers to be rewarded and feel fantastic :)

Answer (score 1):

WebRTC is not a browser technology (though it is well designed for browsers), but a complex of technologies for video/audio/files/messages P2P delivery: codecs, APIs, routers etc.

You can use WebRTC to even transmitting video/audio/messages/files between two servers (still peer to peer, isn't it). Practically, you can use any device with access to local network or Internet and write any program to make it working with WebRTC.

Answer (score 1):

WebRTC defines protocols for sending video and audio and data, and protocols for two endpoints to connect to one another (ICE with STUN and TURN).  While the Javascript bindings are part of the WebRTC standard, some mobile native SDKs implement many of the protocols of WebRTC, but do not strictly present the Javascript bindings.